# How to retrieve ssh password with a working ssh key

Tags: ssh, password, authentication

I always login a server with a ssh key, so I am not sure what my actual password was anymore. I would need to guess a couple of times. However the server has fail2ban and I don't want to trigger that. <strike>Is there any way to check which of my passwords corresponds to the ssh key which is accepted by the server?</strike>

Is there anyway I can check my password after logging in with the ssh-key without triggering fail2ban?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No, there is no relation between an account password and the ssh key.

You can logon to an account with ssh with a key even if it has no password.

---

For the updated question, yes, type:

```
su YOURUSERNAME
```

then try if you remember your password

Comment: Thank you for this answer. I forgot that there is not relation... I broadened the question so that it may now have a solution?

Comment: Yes, if by checking you mean if you can remember it - try with su.

Comment: Or if you are in sudoers set a new password with `sudo passwd YOURUSERNAME`

Comment: I did not have sudo, but your approach with `su USERNAME` worked perfectly! Thanks alot :)

Comment: @laktak How is he gonna do `sudo` without knowing his password? Most people don't change `sudoers` in that way

Comment: `sudo` will work if he has `NOPASSWD` (check with `sudo -l`)

Comment: At least in some cases, you won't be able to login with your ssh key if your password has expired (an unhelpful configuration, but apparently common).

Answer (score 7):

The SSH key is completely independent from the password. Knowing a key is of no help to find the password.

If you're root on the server, you can obtain the password hash. It's in `/etc/shadow` if it's a local account, or it may be retrieved from a network database such as LDAP. On Linux, try `sudo getent shadow $USER`. Once you have the password hash, you can try it offline. If you only have a few password candidates, you can use this one-liner where `$6$stuff$more.stuff` is the second `:`-separated field in `/etc/shadow`:

```
perl -l -pe '$_ = crypt $_, q:$6$stuff$more.stuff:'
```

If you need heavier brute-force, look up software for guided password attack. I'm not familiar enough to make a recommendation.

Of course, if you're root on the server, you can also change the password.

Comment: I like the one-liner, which can be used to automate a check.  If you use `q{...}` you won't need to (backslash) escape the `$` characters in the salt/hash value.

Comment: @user431397: It's possible to contrive some hypothetical use-cases: it's a shared account where multiple people use the password, so you can't change it without interfering with their use of the account, and it would be useful for some reason to find out the password.  Or maybe you were just curious what you used as a password at that point in the past.  (Maybe you remember you used the same password on another system, where you *don't* have root or an SSH authorized key).